# Absolutely convergence of an integral

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $f(x)=\dfrac{cos(x)}{x}$ and $I=\int_1^\infty f(x)dx$:

**a**. Does $I$ absolutely convergent?

**b**. if not, does it conditionally convergent?

I checked in matlab and it seems that a is incorrect but b is correct (and the value is around $-0.33$).I comparing  $\dfrac {-1} x \leq f(x) \leq\dfrac 1 x  $ with limits which does not help. How can I solve both sections?

Comment: Certainly not absolutely convergent. Over the interval from $\frac{\pi}{2}n$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}(n+1)$ we get a contribution greater than $\frac{2}{\pi(n+1}$. It is convergent, argument has been given several times on MSE, usually for $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ but it is the same (integration by parts).

Comment: what does MSE stand for? and why the contribution is greater than $\frac{2}{\pi (n+1)}$?

Comment: Math Stack Exchange. Because the denominator is always  $\le \frac{\pi}{2}(n+1)$ on the interval, and $\int_0^{\pi/2} \cos x=1$, so the integral of $|\cos x|$ over the interval is $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part b) integration by parts yields
$$\int\limits_{1}^{\infty}{\dfrac{\cos{x}}{x}\ dx}=\int\limits_{1}^{\infty}{\dfrac{d(\sin{x})}{x} }=\left. \dfrac{\sin{x}}{x}\right|_{1}^{\infty}+\int\limits_{1}^{\infty}{\dfrac{\sin{x}}{x^2}\ dx },$$
so integral converges conditionally.

Comment: what do you mean by $cosx=d(sinx)$?

Comment: +1. For the second part, I was trying to bound the integrand from above over intervals of length $\pi$ and show that it converges. Integration by parts never struck me for some reason.

Comment: $\cos{x}dx=d(\sin{x})$

Comment: @user17762: Integration by parts can be a useful tool for estimates.

Answer (score 1):

For part $a$, note that
\begin{align}
\int_1^{\infty} \left\vert\dfrac{\cos(x)}x \right \vert dx & \geq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_{(2n+1) \pi-\pi/3}^{(2n+1)\pi} \left\vert\dfrac{\cos(x)}x \right \vert dx \geq \dfrac12 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int_{(2n+1) \pi-\pi/3}^{(2n+1)\pi} \dfrac{dx}x\\
& \geq \dfrac12 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{\pi/3}{(2n+1)\pi} = \dfrac16 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac1{2n+1} = \infty
\end{align}

Comment: why $\begin{align}
\int_1^{\infty} \left\vert\dfrac{\cos(x)}x \right \vert dx \end{align} \geq \sum_0^\infty\int ...$ is correct?

Comment: @theOrthanormalBeginner Because $\cup_{n=0}^{\infty} \left( (2n+1)\pi-\pi/3,(2n+1)\pi\right) \subset (1,\infty)$ and the integrand is positive.